# Website Verification in Facebook Instant Article

Tags: facebook, url, verification, instant

I am trying to add my website to Facebook Instant Article using Connect your site. However, I always get this error:

> The provided URL is not being accepted because the site has minimal
>   readership, which violates the Instant Article Policies
>   (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instant-articles/policy/).
>   Please provide a different URL

I am using SSL by Cloudflare.

What could be the possible reason for this error?

Comment: _“What could be the possible reason for this error?”_ - That your site has minimal readership, maybe? If you need it in even plainer English: Your site not important enough, not enough people care for it to begin with, to justify the use of instant articles. Point A.3 on the poilcy page says, _“Establish a presence on your site before using Instant Articles (i.e. brand new sites may not be eligible to use Instant Articles).”_

Comment: But before some months I added brand new website to facebook instant articles. Is there any policy update as I am getting 500+ visitors daily.

Comment: Dunno what the situation was months ago. But since it says at the very end, _“We reserve the right to change these policies at any time without prior notice.”_ I don’t think you should expect any big announcements in such regards in the first place.

Comment: @CBroe, you're not incorrect, but you're neglecting to acknowledge the fact that Facebook, in general, and in this particular case, is horrendous at proper documentation and disclosure about various policies. It's entirely ambiguous what the meaning of "minimal readership" means, by any meaningful metric or even a sense of order of magnitude. Is it <10K readers, <100K, <1mm. Anyway, it seems the community at large is experiencing the same issue, and no one has a clue why: https://github.com/Automattic/facebook-instant-articles-wp/issues/925

Comment: Btw, at the time of writing, this question has been viewed 2,000 times.

Comment: @CBroe, i am sure the OP understands what the text means. But its not clear how much constitutes "minimal readership".My blogs have 2000+ page views everyday and still it's not enough for fb.

Answer (score -1):

You need at least 15,000 page views to the site before facebook will accept your page. I suggest installing the facebook pixel or google analytics to track this statistic. If you believe your site has passed this minimum threshold, contact facebook customer service.

Comment: Reference to this info?

Comment: @cagatayodabasi facebook does not say how much is needed as of now. they have in the past...

Answer (score -3):

The provided URL is not being accepted because the site has minimal readership, which violates the Instant Article Policies (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instant-articles/policy/). Please provide a different URL.

i have same problem,i think i.a. make some change

Comment: I am not sure why someone has upvoted the answer. as it isn't any solution to the problem.

Comment: Not a solution, just the typical "same problem here".